# Generate a custom Enterprise WSDL

Tags: soap, wsdl

I am trying to **generate a WSDL** that **expose only some** of my objects and **methods**.

The `Enterprise WSDL` expose every object and method that my org has.

I know that it could be possible "*cutting*" the generated XML by hand taking care the dependences, but is there any tool to resolve those dependences? or to regenerate a WSDL from other WSDL choosing the exposed methods?

Comment: What do you hope to achieve by this?

Comment: I would like to have an WSDL which contains just login, query and some custom web services.

Comment: but why? I've seen people mistakenly think this provides some kind of security, which it doesn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual method is manual editing, although it should be possible to use the Eclipse IDE's WSDL editing mode to trim out the extra functions that you don't need. You'll still need to take care not to delete dependencies that are actually required, because Eclipse cannot validate what is or isn't necessary directly.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/71090/20919) says that the Enterprise WSDL content depends on the current user.

If you need to hide Objects or fields, you might want to define all these permissions in a user profile, for a specific webservice user, and generate the WSDL while connected as that user. It should only contain what they're allowed to manipulate.