# Enterprise WSDL: varies depending on user?

Tags: wsdl, privileges

Is there a single enterprise WSDL for my firm, or does the WSDL depend on the user generating it and the privileges granted her?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the Enterprise WSDL respects field and object-level security. This means that the user performing the export will determine which elements appear in the WSDL. You should perform the export as the user that has the correct permissions.